# How does a firm calculate whether a project will generate positive NPV?

Tags: interest-rates

I am stuck on how a firm can calculate whether a project can generate positive NPV. In this scenario I will be assuming an efficient market hypothesis.

My lecturer said that if a project has IRR 12%, and the cost of capital is 10%, then you will generate positive NPV.

Though, I don't see why. Since regardless of the percentage cost of capital, the IRR is set at a breakeven point. So should the cost of capital be 20%, then you will still not be generating positive nor negative NPV.

An explanation into what I am missing or don't understand would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My lecturer said that if a project has IRR 12%, and the cost of capital is 10%, then you will generate positive NPV.

Let's take a concrete example:

```
Project    Borrow (at 10%)  Invest (at 12%)  Net cashflow
Period 0   + $100 (inflow)  - $100 (outflow)     $0
Period 1   - $110 (outflow) + $112 (inflow)    + $2
```

The net cashflow of $2 at period 1 can be discounted back to period 0 at any discount rate to create a positive NPV.

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion arises from the definition of break-even point. Given a set of cash flows the IRR is the rate such that negative and positive cash flows balance out. If you were to use this rate for discounting, the NPV would be $0$. However, there is no reason to use the IRR for discounting. It's just a number. A firm should use its cost of capital because that is what it uses to finance projects.